# Just moved into a new house, what is this tube in the ground outside my wall?

Tags: water

[image]

It looks like there was some kind of a cheese cloth placed on top of it before, but at this point it's been broken.  I can't see the bottom of it, and I have no idea why it's there.  Does anybody have an idea?  I was going to go to the store to get another cheese cloth to place on top of it, but if I can just close it up I'd prefer doing that.  But again, no idea what that is.  It goes down in front of my house, and in my basement it looks like it goes to my pum[ pump?  But it's hard to tell, because while there's a tube coming up from my sump pump, it seems to go up and east of my house.  While the tube pictured above is going down on the south side of my house.  So there would be have to be some bends and perhaps forks in the tubing for that to make sense.

Other than that, I have no idea what is beneath there.  Has anybody seen this before?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you are not familiar with imgur, there's actually 3 images.  ([First](http://imgur.com/5msCQhD,od4wETC,n0ZsbSZ#0), [Second](http://imgur.com/5msCQhD,od4wETC,n0ZsbSZ#1), [Thrid](http://imgur.com/5msCQhD,od4wETC,n0ZsbSZ#2))

Comment: Could it be a clean out for the main drain from your house to the city sewer?

Answer (score 3):

What diameter?

From here it looks like a vent for a drywell or French drain. If it's about 4" (10cm) diameter, that'd add to my suspicion.

Comment: Yes it is 4 inches, give or take.  What is a french drain?  Should I try to fix that cheesecloth looking thing on top of it?

Comment: French drain - trench lined with gravel with a perforated drain tile/pipe down at the bottom to drain off excessive water or lower the water table around foundations. And yes, stuff should be kept from falling in and clogging it. This looks to be there because of a water ponding issue, and I'd use hardware cloth (metal mesh) for durability.

Comment: @FiascoLabs
What should I put on top of it to avoid clogging?

Also, I looked into french drains, and they all look much shallower than mine.  This drain looks really deep, is it definitely a french drain?

Comment: If it goes deep and is to intercept and keep water out of the basement, it would be called a curtain drain (just a lot deeper French drain, meant for more than just reducing surface water). Can you trace an outlet anywhere downhill from the wall it would protect?

Comment: @FiascoLabs no I don't see an outlet, when I go to the basement where it should meet up there's just a closet and nothing on the wall.  I think I'll just go try to buy a grate or something to put over it and call it a day

Comment: The outlet FL was referring to would be outdoors, six or more feet downhill from the "mystery pipe". It'd be the spot where a drain system would "daylight" (discharge drained water).

Comment: It drains outside as @TDHofstetter says. You are trying to keep the water out of the basement by having it exit downhill away from the basement.